# Kubuntu 18.04 Redshift Control Plasmoid has no effect

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, redshift

I added Redshift Control Plasmoid, added some settings, but nothing happens. Running redshift from command line changes colort temperature, but plasmoid always shows 6500K. However mouse wheel up/down changes this value.
Here is screenshots of plasmoid settings:

[image]

[image: redshift plasmoid settings]

What am I missing? Forums say that nothing else has to be done.

Comment: UPD: this happens on laptop Lenovo x260 with two external monitors. However, when I use only built-in monitor, redshift widget works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved it by removing plasmoid and starting redshift from a script (KDE built-in autostart):

```
andreyv@desktop-99:~$ cat ./redshift.sh 
/usr/bin/redshift -v 2>&1 | tee /home/andreyv/log/redshift.log &

andreyv@desktop-99:~$ cat ./.config/redshift.conf 
[redshift]
temp-day=6500
temp-night=4000
transition=0
gamma=1.0
location-provider=manual

[manual]
lat=56.0
lon=60.0
```